# What are the differences among these codes with generics

Tags: java, generics

I noticed that both of the following codes work:

```
private Node<K,V>[] lst=(Node<K,V>[])(new Node[10]);
private Node<K,V>[] lst=new Node[10];
```

Is there any difference between them? To my understanding, `Node` and `Node<K,V>` are of different types, and we cannot create an array with `new Node<K,V>[10]`, so we need to typecast it with `(Node<K,V>[])`. What about the second one? Why does it work without typecasting?

What's more, I noticed the above code doesn't gaurantee the correctness of types in runtime, as the following example:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add("ax");
al.add("bf");
List<Integer>[] list = (List<Integer>[]) new List[]{al};
System.out.println(list[0]); // ["ax", "bf"] printed
```

So my second question is: is there any need to combine array and collections with generics? Is `private Node[] lst=new Node[10];` always a better option?(Here I cannot use `List<List<Integer>>` because I need an array of fixed size). Thanks!

PS: I know some basic knowledge about the erasure of generics by JVM in runtime, I just don't understand how the above code works

Comment: "*`Node` and `Node<K,V>` are of different types*" - no, they are not. You can't, for example, overload on those two. These are the same types, but with or without the generic types. Generic types exist only for the compiler to make you able to omit casting.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  The compiler will tell you that what you’re doing is dangerous and carries the risk of data corruption.  Arrays are never compatible with generics, because generic types are erased at runtime and the array type can only indicate the raw type of each element.